# Want to convert the dictionary data in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqZjI.png)

The is the dictionary format i am getting while pulling the data. I would like to convert this to dataframe.

Tried to convert using this - `df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(min_candledata)`, however receiving below error

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoN3a.png)

I am looking for the data in this format,

Comment: Although there are {} but the input does not look like a dictionary. Please copy paste the actual text and not by image

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: from the images (sigh) and the error, it looks like what you have is a list of `DataFrame`s, and you would use `pd.concat()` to concat them all together. We can't tell without a proper MRE. Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data in the dictionary you share a printscreen is a dictionary where the values are alreadyin the pandas dataframe format. Hence you don't need to use that function.

Your data looks like this

```
min_candledata={"BANKNIFTY1":pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],'b':[2,4,5]}),"BANKNIFTY2":pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],'b':[2,4,5]})}
print(min_candledata)
```

To access a dataframe in the dictionary simply use the key of the dataframe you want to use, e.g.

```
df=min_candledata["BANKNIFTY..."]
```

then proceed in pandas with wathever you want to do